# Setting up a Couchbase Server in Azure

Tags: azure, couchbase

I'm looking to setup a Couchbase Server for some NoSQL development I'm working on. I have found a couple of options online:

1. http://blog.couchbase.com/hosting-couchbase-server-in-windows-azure-part-1
2. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/couchbase/couchbase-server-40-enterprise/ (Couchbase 4.1.0) / https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/couchbase/ (All Couchbase versions)

**My question is, why would we need to do option 1, if option 2 is available?** It seems that with option 2 available, it would be unnecessary to go through the trouble of setting up everything manually as outlined in option 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually have a few more options with the ARM templates for Azure,

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/couchbase-on-ubuntu

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/couchbase-ansible

Option 1: Gives you the most flexibility (you can chose your deployment details from OS to firewall settings and more) but also requires the most work from you.

Option 2: A preset solution (os and configurations are given in advance) makes it easy and you can change settings/configurations later.

Option 3+4: Just like option 2, but deployment is done using the new Resource Manager option in Azure and using a template that you can fully configure/edit.

What options fits your specific needs depends on what you need; If you need Windows Server as OS then option 1 is probably best.